# How to combine multiple "groups" of CSS media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries, retina-display, devicepixelratio

In CSS Media queries, you can use `,` (for "or") and `and` to match media query requirements. For example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (min-resolution: 2dppx) { ... }
```

But what if you wanted to mix `and` and `,` in the same media query? A good use case would be that `min-resolution` is not supported in all browsers. You have to do something like this:

```
@media
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
(min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
(min-resolution: 192dpi),
(min-resolution: 2dppx) { ... }
```

In this case, ANY of those requirements need to match for the media query to take effect.

So now, if I wanted to also require the `min-width: 768px` in the media query how would I do this? Is it possible to group the "or" queries together and separate the group with an `and`? Something like this:

```
@media
(
  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  (min-resolution: 192dpi),
  (min-resolution: 2dppx)
)
and
(min-width: 768px) { ... }
```

The above syntax does not work, but I think it maybe illustrates what I'm trying to get at. It would be sort of like how you group SQL `AND` and `OR` queries together using `(...)` parenthesis.

Is it possible to do this with CSS?

EDIT:

This seems to work but it seems like syntax overkill:

```
@media
  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: 768px),
  (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: 768px),
  (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 768px),
  (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (min-width: 768px)
  { ... }
```

Is that the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like this :

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi), (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (min-width: 768px) {...}
```

> `,` is interpreted as the delimiter in a list of single media queries
>   basically meaning  each media query between the commas is first
>   evaluated, then all of them are ORed together thereby giving the `,` /
>   OR the lowest precedence.
>
> `and` has the highest precedence

Comment: Interesting information about the precedence thing, but that syntax doesn't appear to work. For example, Chrome evaluates it as `@media (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (min-width: 768px), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {...}` So it combines the `and` into a single rule and then that OR any of the rest need to match

Comment: Maybe I have to do this: `@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: 768px), (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: 768px), (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 768px), (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (min-width: 768px)  {...}`. Seems like way overkill though.